# How are participants in a clinical study of a new medication selected and monitored?

Tags: clinical-study

I don't have any background in medicine, but I'm interested. How are participants in a clinical study of a new medication selected and monitored? Do they make an announcement calling for volunteers? Do they pay the volunteers, or volunteers are desperate people who would try any new medication? After selecting the participants, how are they monitored, so that they wouldn't take other medications, recreational drugs, or get involved in stress inducing activities? Are they isolated?

Comment: I expect this varies from study to study. I was put into mine by my oncologist. I could tell you quite a lot about the process, but it might have no relevance to a study on something like ED drugs or insomnia. Also, your "either you get paid or you are desperate and would try anything" is a false dichotomy. And what makes you think people in studies aren't allowed to live a normal life including getting stressed or having a glass of wine? As my study nurse often says, "you're not in jail."

Comment: There are many different ways that no longer include experimenting on prison populations. Name a drug so we can be more specific.